# How to call windows file already exist dialog when a file or directory already exists

Tags: mfc

I am working on my college project. I need to call windows file already exists dialog when it tried to create a new directory or file. If file already exists then it needs to prompt windows file already exist default dialog.

Thank You

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand your problem.

Comment: If you're using `CFileDialog` then set `dwFlags` to `OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT` when constructing the dialog. If not then AFAIK there's no default dialog for this - you'll have to create your own or call `[Afx]MessageBox()`.